# IBOutlet nil while everything looks OK hooked-up

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a strange scenario where an IBOutlet is nil, but it looks like everything is hooked up OK.

The outlet in this example is a simple UILabel in the Main.storyboard

The only thing I can think of is of a bug because it's an Swift project, with a Objective-C component UIViewController. So it looks like there is an issue when you try to hook up IBOutlets.

I can't figure out what is going wrong.. Maybe it IS a bug, or maybe I'm overlooking something while I'm trying for too long now..

Hope someone has the answer...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the error please.

Comment: Are you modifying the PDFKBasicPDFViewer class? Why not make a subclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong initializer in PDFKBasicPDFViewer.m

`- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` should use `[super initWithCoder]`, instead of `[super init]`.

So replace it with following:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

And it will work.

Comment: Wow.. srsly.. Totally overlooked that one.. Good catch!

Comment: Also using your own variable for checking out view is loaded is bad. There is `[self isViewLoaded];`

Comment: Totally agree... This was just a simple demo-app to show the issue. The component used to show the PDF is a third party lib...